# Running JavaScript (and calling jQuery plugins) returned via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web app that uses AJAX to load pages, so once the user is logged in there are no page reloads.

The issue I have is that I return JS on some of the HTML pages loaded via AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#content .wrapper').html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //throw error
    }
});
```

The JS works as expected the first time the page is loaded after a hard refresh but if I go back to the page certain plugins don't work as expected. For example jQueryUI autocomplete and dialog.

An example of some code that might be on the HTML page returned:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#add-recipients-button').click(function() {

        $("#add-recipients").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Add Recipients",
            width: 400,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $('#customer').val('');
                $( "#customer-select" ).autocomplete({
                    source: 'somescript.php',
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#customer").val(ui.item.id);
                    }
                });
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $( "#customer-select" ).autocomplete( "destroy" );
            }
        });

    });

});

</script>
```

Unfortunalty I can't give a live example right now but I hope this is enough info for someone to point out what I am doing wrong and give me a shove in the right direction. I'm guessing its some sort of scope or overloading issue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: order of script vs html on ajax loaded pages is important. `document.ready` has already occurred in main page

Answer (score 0):

You should define your dialog and autocomplete outside the click function, so you can use it after you call back your page

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML it's hard to judge exactly what goes wrong, my guess is that you are overwriting the elements that you are attaching your behaviour to. Ready is only executed once when the document is ready, any changes done to elements inside the document will not be caught by $(document).ready(...);

You might want to create a function that sets up your behaviours within content like below:

```
var enableRecipientsButtonBehaviour = function () {
    $('#add-recipients-button').click(function() {

        $("#add-recipients").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Add Recipients",
            width: 400,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $('#customer').val('');
                $( "#customer-select" ).autocomplete({
                    source: 'somescript.php',
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#customer").val(ui.item.id);
                    }
                });
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $( "#customer-select" ).autocomplete( "destroy" );
            }
        });

    });
}

$(documnent).ready(function () {
  [..]
  enableRecipientsButtonBehaviour();
}

[..]

$.ajax({
  success: function () {
   // Rewrite Content HTML
   enableRecipientsButtonBehaviour();  
}
```

A quick example of what is probably your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/badguy/ykL3nvc5/